# How to replace an object in an array in JavaScript with a one-liner?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array with some object:

```
let array = [
  { name: 'bob', score: 12 },
  { name: 'Joe', score: 20 },
  { name: 'Sue', score: 25 }
]
```

How can I replace Joe's object in the array with this new object in a single line:

```
let newScoreForJoe = { name: 'Joe', score: 21 }
```

I know that I can find the index of Joe's object in the array and then update it like so:

```
let joeIndex = array.findIndex(x => x.name === newScoreForJoe.name)
array[joeIndex] = newScoreForJoe;
```

But is there an elegant one-liner to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Well you could get rid of the `joeIndex` and just do `array[array.findIndex(x => x.name === newScoreForJoe.name)] = newScoreForJoe;`

Comment: I think there will be no better solution, the 'name' property has no  special rule to find.

Comment: did you check y answer?

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu this is the best one. If you add it as an answer I will accept

Comment: @railsuser400 sure, just added. glad that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get rid of the `joeIndex` variable all together and just do:

`array[array.findIndex(x => x.name === newScoreForJoe.name)] = newScoreForJoe;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure how elegant this will be for you but since you are trying to returm an array with the same amuount of objects, i would do this:

The array:

```
let array = [
  { name: 'bob', score: 12 },
  { name: 'Joe', score: 20 },
  { name: 'Sue', score: 25 }
]
```

The object:

```
let newScoreForJoe = { name: 'Joe', score: 21 }
```

The replace line:

```
let joeIndex = array.map(x => x.name === newScoreForJoe.name ? newScoreForJoe : x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this answer. Just change the value of the object property.

```
array[1].score = 21;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and assign the new object inside of the callback.

If no object is found, no assignment happens.

```js
let array = [{ name: 'bob', score: 12 }, { name: 'Joe', score: 20 }, { name: 'Sue', score: 25 }],
    newScoreForJoe = { name: 'Joe',score: 21 };
    
array.some((a, i, aa) => (a.name === newScoreForJoe.name && (aa[i] = newScoreForJoe)));

console.log(array);
```